# ngresource not posting to server on first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Have the following ngresource service

```
app.factory('CardService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/cards/:id', {
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        'update': {method: "PUT"}
    });
});
```

And the following code that uses this service

```
    this.saveSession = function (callback) {
            var thisService = this;

            //acquires the promise to get the snapshot image as data url
            var promise = this.toImage();
            promise.done(function (dataUrl) {
                console.log("promise is called");
                var saveObj = {
                    card_contents: {
                        orientation: thisService.orientation,
                        fold: thisService.card_type,
                        base: thisService.base,
                        content: thisService.canvasItems,
                        snapshot_image: dataUrl
                    }
                };

                if (this.modelInstance == undefined) {
                    console.log("creating new card on server");

                    CardService.save(saveObj, function () {
                        console.log("this is sparta!!");
                        if (callback) {
                            callback();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("updating card on server");
                    this.modelInstance.card_contents = saveObj.card_contents;
                    this.modelInstance.$update({}, function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };

app.controller("SaveSessionCtrl", function ($scope, Canvas) {
    $scope.saveCardSession = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        Canvas.saveSession();
    }
});
```

Think is, when i trigger `saveCardSession` through button click, I got the following strange  behavior. On the first click, `CardService.save` does nothing. (Checked the network tab and my server). On the second click the call to server fires twice.

Any idea why? Using angular and angular-resource 1.1.5 here. Are there any concerns with using jquery defers with angularjs that might be causing this problem?

[image]

**EDIT:**
the toImage method is shown here:

```
this.toImage = function (editorItems, item) {
        var canvasDefer = $.Deferred();

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'stage',
            width: 400,
            height: 400
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);
        var imageObj = new Image();
        var thisService = this;

        imageObj.onload = function () {
            var bgImage = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                image: imageObj,
                width: 400,
                height: 400
            });
            layer.add(bgImage);

            //avoid sorting on the actual component array as other stuff may be watching this
            var clonedItems = [];
            var defers = [];

            var loadImgForCanvas = function (index, item) {
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function () {
                    var userImage = new Kinetic.Image({
                        x: item.x,
                        y: item.y,
                        width: item.width,
                        height: item.height,
                        image: image
                    });

                    if (item.angle) {
                        userImage.rotate(item.angle);
                    }

                    clonedItems[index] = userImage;
                    deferred.resolve();
                }

                image.src = item.blob_url;
                return deferred.promise();
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < editorItems.length; i++) {
                if (editorItems[i].zindex != undefined)
                    clonedItems.push(editorItems[i]);
            }

            //sort by zindex
            clonedItems.sort(function (a, b) {
                a.zindex - b.zindex;
            })

            for (var i = 0; i < clonedItems.length; i++) {
                var component = clonedItems[i];
                if (component.type == "textbox") {
                    var x = component.x;
                    var y = component.y;
                    var w = component.width;
                    var h = component.height;

                    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                        padding: 0,
                        text: component.text.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n"),
                        fill: component.fcolor,
                        fontSize: component.size,
                        fontFamily: component.font
                    });

                    clonedItems[i] = text;
                    //layer.add(text);
                } else if (component.type == 'img') {
                    var deferred = loadImgForCanvas(i, component);
                    defers.push(deferred);
                }
            }

            //layer.draw();
            if (defers.length == 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < clonedItems.length; i++) {
                    layer.add(clonedItems[i]);
                }

                layer.draw();
                stage.toDataURL({
                    callback: function (dataUrl) {
                        canvasDefer.resolve(dataUrl);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $.when.apply($, defers).then(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < clonedItems.length; i++) {
                        layer.add(clonedItems[i]);
                    }

                    layer.draw();
                    stage.toDataURL({
                        callback: function (dataUrl) {
                            canvasDefer.resolve(dataUrl);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };

        imageObj.src = item.front_image;
        return canvasDefer.promise();
    }
```

Comment: How does the toImage promise get resolved?

Comment: Gruff bunny, added my toImage method. Basically, there is a series of defers. 1. the first image onload draws a background image to the canvas and subsequently I have a defer for each image in my editorItems object. When all the image loads and is drawn to the canvas, my promise is resolved...

Comment: That's pretty complex stuff.  As a test, have you tried resolving the promise just before you return from toImage to see if the save is done immediately? My suspicions are that the promise isn't resolved when you think it should be.

Comment: as a test i did a simple setTimeout->resolve in toImage however its the same stuff, ngresource still not behaving the first time round.

Comment: hmm somehow switching to ngresource 1.2.5 resolves the issue. Not sure what's the reason, hope someone can enlighten.